# react-gluejar blob image upload to static server

Tags: reactjs, blob

I'm a newbie trying to use react-gluejar on a REACT app to paste an image from the clipboard into a component and then, upload it to a static server.

Starting from the basic sample:

```
<Gluejar onPaste={files => {console.log(files)}} errorHandler={err => console.error(err)}>
    {
        images => images.length > 0 &&
        <div>
            <img src={images[images.length - 1]} key={images[0]} alt={`Pasted: ${images[0]}`} />
            <Typography style={{ fontSize: "16px" }} > {images[0]} </Typography>
        </div>
     }</Gluejar>
```

the console log above returns something like this after I paste two images on my component:

```
(2) ["blob:http://localhost:3000/3ef4e3d9-b8b0-4545-9d24-9fdcb34cb6e9", "blob:http://localhost:3000/49e641a5-15bd-49dd-a6ff-d97a4055c04e"]
```

I need to create an uploadable object like this:

```
File {name: "214860.jpg", lastModified: 1571432733000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Oct 18 2019 18:05:33 GMT-0300, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 571747, …}lastModified: 571432733000lastModifiedDate: Fri Oct 18 2019 18:05:33 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília) {}name: 214860.jpg"size: 571747type: "image/jpeg"webkitRelativePath: ""__proto__: File
```

How should I proceed in order to create an object like this starting from the Gluejar return showed above?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - change the React-gluejar component to this:

```
<Gluejar onPaste={files => { process(files) }} errorHandler={err => console.error(err)}>
    {
        images => images.length > 0 &&
        <div>
            <img src={images[images.length - 1]} key={images[0]} alt={`Pasted: ${images[0]}`} />
            <Typography style={{ fontSize: "16px" }} > {images[0]} </Typography>
        </div>
    }</Gluejar>
```

and create the *process* method like this:

```
const process = async (selectedImage) => {
    try {
        async function createFile(Myfile) {
            let response = await fetch(Myfile);
            let data = await response.blob();
            let metadata = {
                type: 'image/png'
            };
            let file = new File([data], "test.png", metadata);
            console.log(file)
        }
        createFile(selectedImage);
```

the console log will be:

```
File {name: "test.png", lastModified: 1597521664920, lastModifiedDate: Sat Aug 15 2020 17:01:04 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 6839, …}
```